# Why doesn't this use of emplace_back with deleted copy constructor work?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector, emplace

I have a type that I have deleted the copy constructor from, and I would like to have a `vector` of this type, so I need to create all the elements via `emplace_back`. But, `emplace_back` seems to require a copy constructor, as the compiler gives a warning about not being able to instantiate `emplace_back` because the copy constructor has been deleted. Why does it need a copy constructor? I thought the whole point of `emplace_back` was to build the `vector` without copying anything. Can I even have a `vector` of objects that don't have a copy constructor?

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType(std::array<double, 6> a) {}
    MyType(const MyType& that) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyType> v;
    std::array<double, 6> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    v.emplace_back(a);
}
```

Compiler is clang/llvm.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/9v5w here does not work

Comment: here also http://goo.gl/eLUPjR

Comment: `emplace_back` don't need the copy constructor but when the capacity of vector is not enough to store new element, vector need to reallocate its element, this requires copy/move constructor. By deleting the copy constructor, you also prevent it generating the default move constructor. In this case, declare a move constructor may work

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When the `vector`'s internal storage grows, it will need to *move* the elements from the old storage to the new. [By deleting the copy constructor, you also prevent it generating the default move constructor.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor)

Answer (score 12):

To be able to call emplace_back, your type should either be [EmplaceConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EmplaceConstructible) or [MoveInsertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveInsertable) .
You need to give a move constructor to your class if you have deleted the copy constructor. (Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) for requirements of emplace_back)

```
 MyType(MyType &&a) {/*code*/} //move constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to run this code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
class MyType {
public:
    MyType(std::array<double, 6> a) {
        std::cout<< "constructed from array\n";
        }
    MyType(const MyType& that){
          std::cout<< "copy\n";
    }

    MyType(MyType&& that){
          std::cout<< "move\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyType> v;
    std::array<double, 6> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    v.emplace_back(a);
}
```

You will get the following result:

> constructed from array

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/4o65)

It is clear that just the `constructor` from `std::Array` is called. So, no need for `copy constructor`. But in the same time if you `deleted` the `copy constructor`, the compiler will raise an error (at least on two compilers I tried  [first](http://cpp.sh/9v5w) [second](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNl9jcThNM2dNWms) ). I think that some compilers will check for the existence of `copy constructor` when using emplace_back even if it is not necessary in this practical case while others won't. I do not know what is standard here (which compiler is right or wrong).

Comment: The problem is that `emplace_back` can cause the vector to grow, which needs the objects inside to be movable. And since `MyType` has a user-declared copy constructor, no move constructor is generated and the class is neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: but at least in this case no copy or move was called.. so what is the difference ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi It could be required eventually. Which means there is some code which will be there to handle that case. And for that either the move constructor and copy constructor must be present at compile time.

Comment: The difference is that the code for `emplace_back` contains a call to the move ctor. Control would not have passed through it at runtime, but it must be compilable anyway.